# How could we Invoke SSL Certificate Popup in browser using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ssl, popup

I need to invoke SSL Certificate Viewer(Popup) in the browser using javascript code. Is there any way to do so? If so please get me some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

After some research the answers appears to be a no.

You can, however, instruct the user on how to get to the dialogue, for example (Chrome 33 on Windows):

> To access your HTTPS/SSL certificates in Google Chrome/Chromium:
>
> 1. [Click Here](chrome://settings) to open the Chrome settings panel
> 2. Scroll all the way to the bottom and click on "Show Advanced Settings..."
> 3. Scroll all the way to the bottom again, and under the header "HTTPS/SSL" click on "Manage Certificates"
> 4. You're looking at your certificates now.